# Android 3.1 can not find my .so

Tags: android, android-3.1-honeycomb

I have an android project that uses a custom .so library and when I depoly my app I have looked at that /data/data/"app.name.space"/lib folder and there is my libfoo.so file. When the app loads I get

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2293): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /data/data/"app.name.space"/lib/libfoo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

how do I fix this????

Comment: Looks like its not Android 3.1 that is the problem its Google TV that does not support NDK so it will not load my shared object file.

http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=12

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an .so file for the CPU architecture you're testing on?

Common architectures are armabi, armabi-v7a and x86.

[image]

Comment: yes its in the correct place. Currently I have it in the x86 folder and the armeabi folder shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not Android 3.1 that is the problem its Google TV that does not support NDK so it will not load my shared object file. code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=12